# What is a gated sampling technique?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, sampling

[This](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva537/snva537.pdf?ts=1635895124313&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) application note (page 1) metioned about "gated sampling techniques." I searched but found nothing except that one.

Can anyone explain what it is?

> While naturally sampled peak and valley current mode control methods have been widely used, other control architectures are possible using gated sampling techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gated sampling is a technique where you only look for a signal in a time period when you expect it. For example, if you are trying to reflect a laser off of the moon to measure the moon's distance, you can open the gate 2.5 seconds until about 3 seconds after the laser fires. This decreases the time for random noise and you are likely to have a signal.